# How can a touchscreen monitor transfer touch signal to the computer?

Tags: display, android, touchscreen

I am deploying a web application in a production environment, and am considering touchscreen support for ease of use. I've never used one before, and am wondering on which cable it transfers touch signal to the computer. Probably an auxiliary USB cable? I don't expect the HDMI cable to handle such function.

By the way, does Android have generic driver support for these monitors? I intend to replace Windows 10 PC with cheap Chinese Android boxes (usually Android 7.0 and above) because of their tiny size and low power consumption.

Comment: Usually a touchscreen controller is involved.  A specific driver would be needed for the specific controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes exactly, HDMI is not capable to transfer touch screen signal. you must use additional USB cable

Comment: I've ask some touch frame sellers. It indeed uses a separate USB cable. I'm not sure about screens with built-in touch function though.

Answer (score 0):

If the HDMI port does not transfer data to the computer please explain how the Amazon Fire Stick works.  The only port it has is an HDMI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1222282)